# Unwind on a specific document

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a Accounts collection where details about posts are denormalized into. In each account document, there is a pages field which is an array of subdocument containing information about a post. Each post document has a tag field, given a account id, I am trying to get the pages in the account with appropriate tag grouping, the only problem is, I want grouped documents as siblings of ungrouped ones.

Example :

```
{
_id : "account1",
pages : [
    {
      title : "New Page"
      tag : "novel",
    },
    {
      title : "Another New Page"
      tag : "novel",
    },
    {
      title : "One more New Page"
    }
]
}
```

My query looks like this

```
db.accounts.aggregate([
                {
                    $match : {
                        _id : "account1"
                    }
                },
                { 
                    $unwind: "$pages" 
                }, 
                { 
                    $project: {
                        pages: 1,
                        tag: {
                            $ifNull : ["$pages.tag", "unassigned"]
                        }
                    }
                }, 
                { 
                    $group: { 
                        _id: "$tag", 
                        pages: { 
                            $push: "$pages" 
                        } 
                    } 
                }
])
```

Currently, the output looks like this

```
{
   "_id" : "novel",
   "pages" : [
    {
      title : "New Page"
      tag : "novel",
    },
    {
      title : "Another New Page"
      tag : "novel",
    }
   ]
},
{
  "_id" : "unassigned",
  "pages" : [
    {
      title : "One more New Page"
      tag : "unassigned",
    }
   ]
}
```

But I need to unwrap this unassigned grouping,the output should be like

```
{
   "_id" : "novel",
   "pages" : [
    {
      title : "New Page"
      tag : "novel",
    },
    {
      title : "Another New Page"
      tag : "novel",
    }
   ]
},
{
   title : "One more New Page"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query can get us the expected output:

```
db.accounts.aggregate([
    {
        $match : {
            _id : "account1"
        }
    },
    { 
        $unwind: "$pages" 
    }, 
    { 
        $project: {
            pages: 1,
            tag: {
                $ifNull : ["$pages.tag", "unassigned"]
            }
        }
    }, 
    { 
        $group: { 
            _id: "$tag", 
            pages: { 
                $push: "$pages" 
            } 
        } 
    },
    {  
        $addFields:{
            "data":{
                $cond:[
                    {
                        $eq:["$_id","unassigned"]
                    },
                    "$pages",
                    []
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind:{
            "path":"$data",
            "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays":true
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields:{
            "data":{
                $cond:[
                    {
                        $eq:["$_id","unassigned"]
                    },
                    "$data",
                    "$$ROOT"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot:{
            "newRoot":"$data"
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

**Data set:**

```
{
    "_id" : "account1",
    "pages" : [
        {
            "title" : "New Page",
            "tag" : "novel"
        },
        {
            "title" : "Another New Page",
            "tag" : "novel"
        },
        {
            "title" : "One more New Page"
        },
        {
            "title" : "New page 2"
        },
        {
            "title" : "New page 3"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Output:**

```
{ "title" : "One more New Page" }
{ "title" : "New page 2" }
{ "title" : "New page 3" }
{
    "_id" : "novel",
    "pages" : [
        {
            "title" : "New Page",
            "tag" : "novel"
        },
        {
            "title" : "Another New Page",
            "tag" : "novel"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Explanation:** After the pages are grouped on the basis of tags, the unassigned pages are projected as a new field `data`. We would then unwind the array. Later on, the documents with tags are also assigned to `data` field i.e the `data` now contains both unassigned pages and group of assigned pages. Finally, we can project `data` as root document.

Comment: Amazing, that did the trick, thanks a lot for the solution. I also wanted to sort the documents so that the grouped pages comes before the ungrouped ones, in order to add this, I renamed unassigned as zzzzzunassigned and added a sort stage right after the group stage.
```
{
        $sort : {
            _id : 1
        }
    }
```
This works well, I just wanted to know if this is right as having to rename unassigned looks ugly. Thanks again for all your help, really appreciate it.

Comment: One way is to keep the tag as ```null``` and sort in descending order. It would bring null at the end. Also, it's fine renaming it as ```zzzz```, but make sure you add proper reason behind that in the code where you would use this query.